# Is it possible to install dependencies from go in go?

Tags: go, dependencies, command-line-interface

I want to have an install/download option in my code so that after I run `go build app.go`, I can run `./app install` to install all the necessary dependencies for the project. Can I do this?

Would the way to approach this be using the command line through go?

Comment: Do not use file name arguments on go build.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your program behave accordingly to the arguments provided when executing:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    args := os.Args[1:]

    if len(args) > 0 && args[0] == "install" {
        fmt.Println("install you dependencies")
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("execute your program")
}
```